# What equation is being used- chamber pressure v.s. mass flow rate? (Cold-gas thruster)

Tags: propulsion, specific-impulse, pressure, combustion-chamber, cold-gas-thrusters

I am doing a project on cold gas thrusters and have seen a couple of graphs relating chamber pressure against mass flow rate. I can't seem to find the equation that relates these two parameters to produce this asymptotic 1/ln |x| looking graph.

Image 1 [https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323629454_Influence_of_combustion_chamber_pressure_on_injector_performance]

[image]

Another similar graph is a screenshot from a YouTube video (link provided below, at 12:06 minutes).

Image 2 [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ar2kTgFQsI]

[image]

If anyone could help locate this equation for me, it would be much appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the graph you are asking about in a way that does not involve watching a video. If you are not yet allowed to post pictures, post a link and someone will edit it in for you.

Comment: I've edited the question!

Comment: Thanks, looks good. One more thing, you should always provide a link or at least site your sources (where you got the graphs from). Welcome to space stack exchange!

Comment: Thanks :) I've provided all the references above each image!

Comment: I believe there may be a free online copy of an early edition of Rocket Propulsion Elements by Sutton online somewhere. I'd suggest doing a search for that and then ploughing into it.  I couldn't say whether you will find nice equations easily or only with a lot of digging though.

Comment: That all said, looking at the charts this seems to be more an exercise of calculating fluid flow from the tank to the combustion chamber. You may have an easier time just looking up flow through a pipe or orifice. The chances are that these plots have been produced from something quite simple though where specific assumptions have been made about various parameters.